Representation of real numbers using irreducible fraction
I am currently going through a textbook studying continued fractions. Unfortunately the textbook has a theorem proof of which I cannot wrap my head around.

If $\tau > 1$ then any real number $\alpha$ can be represented as $$\alpha = \frac{P}{Q}+\frac{\theta}{Q\tau};\ 1 \leq Q \leq \tau;\ gcd(P, Q) = 1;\ |\theta|<1$$

And the proof goes like this:

If $\alpha$ is irrational then the theorem follows from section 1.5.7 and equation 1.3 if we consider $Q$ as $Q_s$ such that $$Q_s \leq \tau < Q_{s+1}$$ but if we take rational $\alpha = \frac{a}{b}$ then this reasoning applies only if $\tau < b$, but the theorem works if we consider $$P=a;\ Q = b;\ \theta = 0$$
1.5.7: $$|\alpha - \delta_s| \leq\frac{1}{Q_s Q_{s+1}} $$ where $Q_s$ is denominator of the convergent $\delta_s$


1.3: $$\epsilon_s = P_s Q_{s+1}-Q_s P_{s+1}$$ where $Q_s$ is denominator and $P_s$ is the numerator of the convergent $\delta_s$

First of all I don't understand why $\tau$ has to be bounded like that? If it's larger than $Q_{s}$ then $$\frac{1}{Q_s\tau} < \frac{1}{Q_s Q_{s+1}}$$ and we can find $\theta$ to form $\alpha$.
Second of all for any number can we find $Q_s$ and $Q_{s+1}$ such that $\tau$ is bounded by them?
Please help me make sense of this proof.
